# Size of formatted string

Tags: c, printf, sizeof

I am struggling to understand what happens during `snprintf`.
Let's say I have two numbers:

```
int i =11; int k = 3;
```

I want to format them like this `"[%02d] %03d\t"` and use `snprintf`.
Afterwards I use the resulting string with `write()`.

`snprintf` needs the length/bytes n. 
I do not understand what is the length I need to provide... 
I have 2 theories:

a) It is

```
sizeof(int)*2
```

b) I check how many chars the formatted string will contain by counting the digits of the two integers and adding the other chars that the output will have:

```
2*sizeof(char) + 1*sizeof(char) + 2*sizeof(char) + 3*sizeof(char)+ 1*sizeof(char)
```

-> digits of i + digits of k + zeros added to first int + zeros added to second int + tab

I am struggling to understand what is the "n" I have to give to `snprintf`

Comment: The size you provide as the second argument is the size of the buffer that `snprintf` will write the text into. ***And*** there's a "trick" to get to know the amount of characters needed by using `snprintf` itself (hint: what does it return?). Please see e.g. [this `printf` (and family) reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) for details.

Comment: By the way, `sizeof(int)` gives you the size of an `int`, not the number of digits it can hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### It is the buffer size

According to a [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/):

> Maximum number of bytes to be used in the buffer. The generated string
>   has a length of at most n-1, leaving space for the additional
>   terminating null character. size_t is an unsigned integral type.

Suppose you write to an array such as this:

```
char buf[32];
```

The buffer can hold 32 chars (including the null terminator). Therefore we call the function like this:

```
snprintf (buf, 32, "[%02d] %03d\t", i, k);
```

You can also check the return value to see how many chars have been written (or would have been written). In this case, if it's bigger than 32, then that would mean that some characters had to be discarded because they didn't fit.

Answer (score 2):

Pass `0` and `NULL` first to obtain an exact amount

```
int n = snprintf(NULL, 0, "[%02d] %03d\t", i, k);
```

Then you know you need `n + 1`

```
char *buf = malloc(n + 1);
snprintf(buf, n + 1, "[%02d] %03d\t", i, k);
free(buf);
```

See it on ideone: https://ideone.com/pt0cOQ

Answer (score 2):

`n` is the size of the string you're passing into `snprintf`, so it knows when to stop writing to the buffer. This is to prevent a category of errors knows as buffer overflows. `snprintf` will write `n - 1` characters into the passed-in buffer and then terminate it with the null character.